# Setting opcache per site

Tags: apache-2.4, php7

Is it possible to set opcache options per site in Apache? I'm trying to disable it via local php.ini in site directory or site config file but it is always enabled. After every config change I restarted Apache and PHP fpm service to apply new config.

Comment: How is PHP called from apache?

Comment: PHP is executed via module in Apache

Comment: You will have to stop using mod_php and migrate to mod_proxy & mod_proxy_fcgi  -> php-fpm. In the process you will be able to change the mpm you are using in httpd to event, so it's a win win.